# Firebase deploy issue with "npmrc"

Tags: firebase, deployment, config

When I run firebasebase deploy --only functions, keep on getting error

Error: double-loading config "/Users/zoyamilovanova/.cache/firebase/runtime/npmrc" as "global", previously loaded as "user"

What can be an issue?